# Repeated roots of biquadratic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is condition for repeated roots of the fourth order polynomial

$$ x^4 + a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d = 0 ?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A polynomial has roots with multiplicity greater than one iff its [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) is zero.

The discriminant of your generic fourth-degree polynomial is:
$$a^2 b^2 c^2-4 b^3 c^2-4 a^3 c^3+18 a b c^3-27 c^4-4 a^2 b^3 d+16 b^4 d+18 a^3 b c d-80 a b^2 c d-6 a^2 c^2 d+144 b c^2 d-27 a^4 d^2+144 a^2 b d^2-128 b^2 d^2-192 a c d^2+256 d^3.$$

Comment: omg  Is there any more visually recognizable raster/matrix form of the double line discriminant?

Comment: @Narasimham: if you translate the variable in such a way that $a=0$ (that does not affect the multiplicity of roots nor the discriminant) then the discriminant is just: $$ -4 b^3 c^2 - 27 c^4 + 16 b^4 d + 144 b c^2 d - 128 b^2 d^2 + 256 d^3$$

Answer (score 0):

If you replace $x$ with $x-a/4$ and simplify, the new polynomial will have roots shifted so their sum is $0$, but the repeating character (or not) will be the same as before.  The new polynomial will look like: $$x^4+Bx^2+Cx+D$$.  If its discriminant is $0$ there will be repeated roots:  $$16D(B^2-4D)^2-27C^4-4B(B^2-36D)C^2=0$$.  Note that the repeated roots may be complex numbers.

Comment: Please note that your equation can be reduced to a quadratic by setting $C^2=c$.